# Spring - mvc ( SimpleFormController ) with hibernate database insertion

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have made one example , In which I have used Spring - mvc and hibernate. I have successfully insert data in the database table but after that I have refresh the page new entry is inserted.

Required Solution : When I refresh the page the database entry would not be inserted second time.

Comment: Removing the `[hibernate]` tag, there is nothing hibernate related in this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Required Solution : When I refresh the page the database entry would not be inserted second time.

Then send a *redirect* after submit (by returning a [`RedirectView`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html)).